# Value of a variable using WinDbg

Tags: c++, winapi, windbg

**Question:**

How to display the **value** of a **C++** **iterator** using WinDbg, illustrated **below:**

```
for (vector<string>::iterator i = args.begin(); i != args.end(); i++)
//omitted
//for instance:
} else if (*i == "-i") {//attempting to display the value of *i
        ++i;
        if (!::PathFileExistsA(i->c_str()))
        {
```

**Note:**

Using **??** evaluate C++ expression command, which displays the following:

```
0:000> ?? i

class std::_Vector_iterator<std::basic_string<char,
std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> >,
std::allocator<std::basic_string<char,
std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> > > >

   +0x000 _Mycont          : 0x0012ff40 std::_Container_base_secure
   +0x004 _Mynextiter      : (null) 
   +0x008 _Myptr           : 0x009c6198 

std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >
```

- Can another command **display/print** the value of `*i` - please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
dt -r i
```

Which will recursively dump the iterator.  One of the members should be the info you seek.  Verbose, but effective.

Comment: Thanks jeffamaphone! Data was at `+0x000 _Buf`

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty is that `*i` invokes a function call to `operator*` on the iterator.  The string you want is likely being pointed to by `_Myptr` at `0x009c6198`.